# Update CollectionView´s size inside a UicollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am finding struggle with some issues to solve.

I am making a app with a uicollectionview which the cells can have another uicollectionview inside it, and so on.
The size of a cell is the full contentSize of the uicollectionview inside that cell.

Imagine i have this stucture in the app:

```
MainCollection
    --Cell
        ...
    --Cell_6
      --ColectionviewA
        --Cell
          ...
        --Cell_66
          -- CollectionViewB
              --Cell_667
```

For example, the size of the **Cell_667** is total dynamic accordion of the size of a async image downloaded from the web. After the cell download is image, it needs to update it's size.

Theres when i find my problem, how can i tel the ***"collectionview father"*** of the cell tu update its size, and then to advise is "father" to update is size, until reach the MainCollection.

Something like:

**Cell_667**(updateSizeCell) ->  **CollectionViewB**(updateFrameSize) ->  **Cell_66**(updateSizeCell) -> **CollectionviewA**(updateFrameSize) -> **Cell_6**(updateSizeCell)-> **MainCollection**(updatecontentSize)

The goal is to maintain a single scroll. 
I simple solution was to advise MainCollection to reload all the cells, but i want avoid that. Any idea how to make this the more eficient and clean way?

Any tips will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're basically trying to do is figure out when the `contentSize` of your collection views is changing. There are a few ways you can accomplish this.

The most straightforward method would probably be to use Key-Value Observing.

After initializing each of your collection views, add your observer to them like this:

```
[myCollectionView addObserver:self forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(contentSize)) options:0 context:nil];
```

Then, implement the actual observation method:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(contentSize))])
    {
        UICollectionView *updatedCollectionView = (UICollectionView *)object;
        // update whatever you need to update here.
    }
}
```

The last bit is just to remember to remove the observer when you are deallocating it (in case the view outlives the observer)

```
[myCollectionView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(@selector(contentSize))];
```

For more info, check out [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) and [Mattt Thompson's great post about it](http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/).

Comment: But still have a problem. My collectionView update it´s contentSize. How the cell(who have the collectionView), knows that needs to update it´s size to fit the same size of the collectionView?

Comment: Have you tried calling `- (void)reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths`? Then passing in the indexPath of the inner collection view.

Comment: but the contentSize of the collectionView only get "bigger" if i change the size of the cell itself